# apache2 mod_rewrite enable, but not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I have enabled mod_rewrite on my server and confirmed it using phpinfo() and it shows as enabled.

I have the following in my httpd.conf file:

```
ServerName 172.16.1.114

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/test$ /index.php
```

I've tried the rewrite rule on another server and it works as expected.  No errors are thrown to my apache error log and it restarts cleanly.  When I try the page it 404s and doesn't load index.php

I'm sure this must be a simple problem, but I am at a loss on how to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Still working on this.  In case it is useful, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and apache 2.2.22

Comment: Have you enabled reqritelog?

Comment: Hi, yes we have and no error messages came through.

Comment: What is your `LogLevel` set to? Default is `warn`, increase it to `debug` if you haven't already, restart Apache and try again, and update your post with what you see in the logs. If you still don't see useful information, enable RewriteLog as Krist van Besien suggested, more here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: Hi, I have set LogLevel to debug, but nothing of relevance shows with respect to mod_rewrite.  I also have RewriteLog enabled, but nothing is written to that log.

Comment: You have to add rewritelog and rewriteloglevel. If however nothing is written in your log then the rewriterule isn't even being considered. In that case something is preventing rewrites altogether.

Answer (score 1):

check in web directory the hidden file called .htaccess . If exist Open the file and check the settings.
404 page is for page do not exist. Check the apache error log also

Comment: Hi, there is no .htaccess file.  Apache is also showing no errors.

Comment: a2enmod rewrite ,run this command once again and restart the apache and after restart check the logs, I expect you have defined apache error log in conf file

Comment: Hi, I've run that a few times to no avail.  In the end I have worked around the problem by doing it via .htaccess file which worked first time.  I was never able to solve the original problem.